# Django filter is not working even after search filter is applied in the url path and also in drf UI

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

This is my code:

models.py

```
class StoreLists(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store_name_ = models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stores'
```

serializers.py

```
class StoreListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StoreLists
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
class StoreListView(generics.GenericAPIView): # even tried with viewsets and ListModelView
    serializer_class = StoreListSerializer
    queryset = StoreLists.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ("store_name", "brand")

    def get(self, request):
        sales = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=sales, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

```
GET - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/store_list - getting all data

GET - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/store_list?brand=samplebrand  - getting all data (filter is not working, same with search filter)
```

Even added django_filters in application and also tried in postman and drf UI but not able to filter.`

Comment: Have you added 'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend' to "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS" in project settings?

Comment: Why you are overriding get() method ? It will work without get() as well. If you want I can share the full example where you can use filterset-fields with modelviewsets

Comment: @Negar37 I think if you mention in the viewsets then you don't need to specify in the settings file

Comment: I have added 'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend' into settings.py @Negar37

Comment: First thing, If you have read docs, there mentioned that a `variable` name must not be end with and `_`, and one of your models' field `store_name_` ends with it, also don't give field name like `store__name`, because that's way field lookups work.

Comment: Can you please share the example of filterset-fields with modelviewsets @DeepakTripathi

Comment: @Harry I have posted the code now you can do all your stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using django-filters then you should follow the below steps.
I have followed these steps in my project

```
#settings.py
  #...
  INSTALLED_APPS += ["django_filters"]
  REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS"]=[
        "django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend",
        "rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter",
    ]
  #...

#views.py
class TableMetaView(ModelViewSet):

serializer_class = TableMetaSerializer
queryset = TableMeta.objects.all()
renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
filterset_class = TableFilter
ordering_fields = ["created_on", "modified_on"]
ordering = ["id", "-modified_on"]

permission_classes = [
    UserHasDatasetChangeAccess & IsTableEditable,
]

def get_queryset(self):
    if getattr(self, "swagger_fake_view", False):
        # queryset just for schema generation metadata
        return TableMeta.objects.none()
    return TableMeta.objects.filter(
        dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet, id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, ""))
    )
```

#TableFilter is imported from custom_filter.py
#custom_filter.py

```
class TableFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = TableMeta
        fields = {
            "name": ["exact", "icontains"],
            "schema_name": ["exact"],
            "type": ["exact"],
        }
```

#urls.py

```
router.register(r"table-meta", TableMetaView, basename="table-meta")
```